# Web API 2 Calling Complex Type Constructor

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API and I am trying to integrate it into a project I am working on.

I am posting a complex type to a WebApi action, but when I do, it calls my type constructor, which ends up overwriting the values I am posting to the method.

Is this normal? I see the actual values in fiddler and I want to keep those when deserializing the object. Is there a different way I should be achieving this? Any help or knowledge would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Here is my class:

```
public class PageOptions
{
    public List<ControlOption<MacroDataType>> DataTypeOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ControlOption<string>> FcastSourceOptions { get; set; }
    public ModalOptions<CorpRegionFilter, CorpRegionSort> CorpCodeOptions { get; set; }
    public ModalOptions<EmptyFilter, EmptySort> BusinessLineOptions { get; set; }
    public ModalOptions<EmptyFilter, EmptySort> SubCategoryOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ControlOption<string>> RollingMonthOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ModalSelection<BusLineInfo>> AddBusinessLineOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ControlOption<AxisDates>> AxisDateOptions { get; set; }
    public List<ControlOption<GraphOptions>> GraphOptionsOptions { get; set; }
    public List<MacroLineOptions> MacroLines { get; set; }
    public List<MacroNote> MacroNotes { get; set; }
    public List<CompareLineOptions> CompareLines { get; set; }
    public Boolean CompareAllToOne { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public GraphStyles GraphStyle { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public CalendarStyles CalendarStyle { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public AxisDates AxisDate { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public LineCompareType ComparisonType { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String SubTitle { get; set; }
    public Boolean ScaleResults { get; set; }
    public Boolean ShowTabulation { get; set; }
    public Boolean ThickLines { get; set; }
    public Boolean BrowseByCorp { get; set; }
    public Boolean ShowUserName { get; set; }
    public Boolean PrintLargeFont { get; set; }
    public Boolean Enable3D { get; set; }
    public Boolean Launch { get; set; }
    public Boolean Promotion { get; set; }
    public Boolean PriceEIChange { get; set; }
    public Boolean LocalEvent { get; set; }
    public Boolean Miscellaneous { get; set; }
    public BrowseByCorpData BrowseByCorpData { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> LineColors { get; set; }
    public String NativeId { get; set; }
    public String FullUserName { get; set; }
    public MacroLineOptions DefaultLineConfig { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> DefaultLineColors { get; set; }
    public LineFormStates FormStates { get; set; }
    public int CurrentLineIndex { get; set; }
    public String ChartImageURI { get; set; }

    public PageOptions()
    {

        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

        // Current User Id
        NativeId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        using (var client = new MacroDataServiceClient())
        {
            FullUserName = client.GetUsersFullName(NativeId);
        }

        // Add the Lines
        MacroLines = new List<MacroLineOptions>();
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 1, Description = "Line 1" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 2, Description = "Line 2" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 3, Description = "Line 3" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 4, Description = "Line 4" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 5, Description = "Line 5" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 6, Description = "Line 6" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 7, Description = "Line 7" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 8, Description = "Line 8" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 9, Description = "Line 9" });
        MacroLines.Add(new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 10, Description = "Line 10" });
        DefaultLineConfig = new MacroLineOptions() { LineId = 1, Description = "" };

        // Add Business Line Options
        AddBusinessLineOptions = new List<ModalSelection<BusLineInfo>>();
        using (var client = new MacroDataServiceClient())
        {
            client.GetAllBusinessLineData()
                .Where(x => x.BusLnCd == "A64" || x.BusLnCd == "A08" || x.BusLnCd == "A54" || x.BusLnCd == "A85" || x.BusLnCd == "A09")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x =>
                {
                    AddBusinessLineOptions.Add(new ModalSelection<BusLineInfo>() { Description = textInfo.ToTitleCase(x.BusLnNm.ToLower()), Selections = new List<BusLineInfo>() { new BusLineInfo() { Code = x.BusLnCd, Name = textInfo.ToTitleCase(x.BusLnNm.ToLower()) } } });
                });
        }

        // DATATYPES
        DataTypeOptions = new List<ControlOption<MacroDataType>>();
        using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
        using (var client = new MacroDataServiceClient())
        {
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            var sales = client.GetFilteredMacroDataTypes(MacroDataTypeSection.Sales).Select(x => new ControlOption<MacroDataType>(x.DataType, x.DisplayName, "Sales")).ToList();
            var recruiting = client.GetFilteredMacroDataTypes(MacroDataTypeSection.Recruiting).Select(x => new ControlOption<MacroDataType>(x.DataType, x.DisplayName, "Distributor Force")).ToList();
            var other = client.GetFilteredMacroDataTypes(MacroDataTypeSection.Other).Select(x => new ControlOption<MacroDataType>(x.DataType, x.DisplayName, "Other")).ToList();
            var daily = client.GetFilteredMacroDataTypes(MacroDataTypeSection.Daily).Select(x => new ControlOption<MacroDataType>(x.DataType, x.DisplayName, "Daily")).ToList();

            DataTypeOptions.Add(new ControlOption<MacroDataType>(MacroDataType.NoSelection, "No Selection"));
            DataTypeOptions.AddRange(sales);
            DataTypeOptions.AddRange(recruiting);
            DataTypeOptions.AddRange(other);
            DataTypeOptions.AddRange(daily);
        }

        // FCAST SOURCE
        FcastSourceOptions = new List<ControlOption<string>>();
        FcastSourceOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("00", "Current Fcst"));
        int count = 1;
        for (var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1); date >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-61); date = date.AddMonths(-1))
        {
            var strVal = String.Format("{0:00}", count++);
            var strText = String.Format("{0:00}/{1} EOM Fcst", date.Month, date.Year);
            FcastSourceOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>(strVal, strText));
        }

        // CORP CODES
        CorpCodeOptions = new ModalOptions<CorpRegionFilter, CorpRegionSort>();
        CorpCodeOptions.SortList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Selected = false, Text = "Corp Code", Value = (int)CorpRegionSort.CorpCode });
        CorpCodeOptions.SortList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Selected = false, Text = "Corp Name", Value = (int)CorpRegionSort.CorpName });
        CorpCodeOptions.SortList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Selected = false, Text = "Region/Corp Code", Value = (int)CorpRegionSort.RegionCorpCode });
        CorpCodeOptions.SortList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Selected = false, Text = "Region/Corp Name", Value = (int)CorpRegionSort.RegionCorpName });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "status", Selected = false, Text = "All", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.AllStatus, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "status", Selected = true, Text = "Active", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.ActiveStatus, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "status", Selected = false, Text = "Planned", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.PlannedStatus, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "region", Selected = true, Text = "All", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.AllRegion, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "region", Selected = false, Text = "AAP", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.AAPRegion, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "region", Selected = false, Text = "AJL", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.AJLRegion, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "region", Selected = false, Text = "EU", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.EURegion, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "region", Selected = false, Text = "NABR", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.NABRRegion, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Group = "region", Selected = false, Text = "US", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.USRegion, OptionType = "radio" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Selected = false, Text = "Catalog", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.Catalog, OptionType = "checkbox" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { Selected = false, Text = "Other", Value = (int)CorpRegionFilter.Other, OptionType = "checkbox" });
        CorpCodeOptions.FilterList.Add(new ModalDropdownOption { });
        CorpCodeOptions.SelectedSort = CorpRegionSort.RegionCorpCode;

        // BUSINESS LINES
        BusinessLineOptions = new ModalOptions<EmptyFilter, EmptySort>();
        // Add filters/Sorts here

        // SUBCAT
        SubCategoryOptions = new ModalOptions<EmptyFilter, EmptySort>();
        // Add filters/Sorts here

        // ROLLING MONTHS
        RollingMonthOptions = new List<ControlOption<string>>();
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("1", "1 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("2", "2 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("3", "3 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("4", "4 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("5", "6 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("7", "7 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("8", "8 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("9", "9 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("10", "10 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("11", "11 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("12", "12 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("18", "18 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("24", "24 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("36", "36 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("48", "48 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("60", "60 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("72", "72 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("84", "84 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("96", "96 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("108", "108 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("120", "120 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("132", "132 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("144", "144 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("156", "156 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("168", "168 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("180", "180 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("192", "192 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("204", "204 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("216", "216 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("228", "228 Month"));
        RollingMonthOptions.Add(new ControlOption<string>("240", "240 Month"));

        // MACRO NOTES
        MacroNotes = new List<MacroNote>();

        GraphOptionsOptions = new List<ControlOption<GraphOptions>>();
        GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.ShowTabulation, "Show Tabulation", null, GraphOptions.ShowTabulation.ToString()));
        GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.ThickLines, "Thick Lines", null, GraphOptions.ThickLines.ToString()));
        GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.BrowseByCorp, "Browse By Corp", null, GraphOptions.BrowseByCorp.ToString()));
        GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.ShowUserName, "Show User Name", null, GraphOptions.ShowUserName.ToString()));
        //GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.ShowNotes, "Show Notes", null, GraphOptions.ShowNotes.ToString()));
        //GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.PrintLargeFont, "Print Large Font", null, GraphOptions.PrintLargeFont.ToString()));
        //GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.Enable3D, "Enable 3D", null, GraphOptions.Enable3D.ToString()));
        GraphOptionsOptions.Add(new ControlOption<GraphOptions>(GraphOptions.ScaleResults, "Scale Results", null, GraphOptions.ScaleResults.ToString()));

        // Add the maximum number of comparison lines
        CompareLines = new List<CompareLineOptions>();
        CompareLines.Add(new CompareLineOptions());
        CompareLines.Add(new CompareLineOptions());
        CompareLines.Add(new CompareLineOptions());
        CompareLines.Add(new CompareLineOptions());
        CompareLines.Add(new CompareLineOptions());

        LineColors = new List<List<String>>() { new List<String>() { "#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618" }, new List<String>() { "#990099", "#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00" }, new List<String>() { "#b82e2e", "#316395" } };
        DefaultLineColors = LineColors;

        // Add other options
        FormStates = new LineFormStates();
        GraphStyle = GraphStyles.Trend;
        CalendarStyle = CalendarStyles.Calendar;
        ComparisonType = LineCompareType.None;
        ShowTabulation = true;
        ThickLines = true;
        ShowUserName = true;
        PrintLargeFont = true;
        Enable3D = true;
        ScaleResults = true;
        CurrentLineIndex = 0;
        BrowseByCorpData = new BrowseByCorpData() { BrowseByCorpList = new List<CorpInfo>(), SelectedCorp = new CorpInfo() };


    }

}
```

And this is my Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("SimplePost")]
public void PostPageOptions([FromBody] PageOptions value)
{
}
```

Like I mentioned, my fiddler shows the right values, but it seems it calls my constructor and it using my initialization values instead inside the Web API Method.

Could it be that my Class is too large? When I use a smaller class, it seems to work.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your method and constructor?

Comment: Show us the complex type and the method. Does the complex type have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Should be set, sorry about that.

Comment: Fiddler shows values but is it in the right format? Do you have the correct Content-Type header?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal.  When you pass a complex type to web api the object is actually read by the api controller as a string and serialized into the correct object determined by the signature.  But to do this the base constructor of the class is invoked, so in your case you parameterless constructor is invoked, and then the controller attempts to populate the properties that were passed in the sting representation of the object.  basically to fix it you will need to have a base parameterless constructor that has no initialization values

Comment: I have done this. I changed it so my default constructor does nothing. Therefore, when the call comes in, it hits this, but inside the Post method it shows all nulls instead of the values coming from the post from the client.

Comment: that actually means the object is not getting to the controller for some reason.  A few things jump out at me in you method singature that could be the problem, you don't actually need any of the decorator tags in a web api controller. your controller could simply look like 

public void PostPageOptions( PageOptions value){}

Comment: if that didn't work will you please show the code of where you call the controller from?

Comment: It seems to work, removing the attribute [FromBody]. Is it true that if you use simple types (string, int, etc.) that you do need this? Or is that also false?

Comment: Honestly i am not sure.